# R[oman|everse] Polish Notation

Tags: code-golf, parsing

It is the year MDLXVII in a world in which the Roman Empire never fell, and the collapse into the dark ages never occurred. Due to the extended period of Pax Romana, the empire's economic stability enabled technology to progress at a rapid rate.

The Romans have begun to dabble with circuitry, and have invented an ingenious calculator that doesn't require the use of an "equals" button. They call it "Roman Polish Notation"

To make a calculation, they enter their operands first, then the operation.

For example, 100 + 11 * 20 would be `C XI XX * +`.

**Additionally**

The Romans have found that they often need to make multiple calculations at the same time, and would prefer for the method to return every value "on the stack" in some sort of array/list/tuple-like structure. (e.g. `X I + X I - CC II +` would return [11, 9, 202])

---

The challenge is to develop a calculator program capable of making these computations.

**Clarification**: Subtractive Notation is required. I hadn't realized it wasn't recognized feature in the Ancient Roman empire. The task was therefore ambiguous, and I apologize.

**Minimum Guidelines**

- Your output will be in Arabic Numerals.
- You only need to convert from Roman Numerals up to 5000.
- You will need to support +, -, /, * operations (addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication).
- Whether division is floating point based or integer based is implementation specific. Either works for this challenge.
- Your output will need to support numbers up to 4 Billion.
- Shortest answer overall, AND in each language wins. This is a Code Golf Challenge but I love the variety.

In the event of a tie, <s>factors like support for roman numerals above 5000 or additional operations will be considered</s> the earliest submission will win.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of strings, each have either a Roman number or an operator?

Comment: can the input be taken in lowercase, or does it have to be uppercase?

Comment: @JesseDanielMitchell As a note... [try not to change rules and invalidate existing answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1347). Also, (as usual) I suggest posting in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [roman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/roman), 118 bytes

```python
from roman import*
s=[]
for i in input().split():s+=[eval(s.pop(-2)+i+s.pop())if i in"+-/*"else`fromRoman(i)`]
print s
```

#### Demo

It cannot be tested online because of the module it makes use of, but you can see how  to run this [here](https://tio.run/##JUw9C8MgEN39FYeTRpJCxkKmTFkzFUIgGZQeGD08W@ivt9oO7xPeo09@xjCW4lK8oOIMgBfFlDvB07YLFxMgYG0DvbLSA5PHqnc202bfp1c8UCTVj9qg@Xut0f1G0vS3TlrP9mj/a7tXqI9dUMKQgUuRD1jAQOMe5hmWmuQX) (a full program accepting input from STDIN – an expression with quotes – and printing the output to STDOUT – in the form of a list, the stack). Uses a slightly older version, because I won't bother to create a new GIF for only a few bytes:

[image: Demo GIF]

To install the package, you can run the following in the Terminal / Command Line:

```python
pip install roman
```

Comment: `pyTester/Py.py` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @totallyhuman It's just a dummy project that I made just for this...

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 217 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to Bruce Forte. -73 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen.*

```hs
foldl(!)[].words
s@ ~(x:y:z)!n=last$(a n:s):[y`f`x:z|(f,c)<-zip[(+),(-),(*),(/)]"+-*/",n==[c]]
a s=last$0:[n+a(drop(length x)s)|(n,x)<-zip l$words"I IV V IX X XL L XC C CD D CM M",x<=s,x++"Y">s]
l=[1,4,5,9]++map(10*)l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5Ba8IwGEDv/RWfoYekSafCdlgwY1AvBb1KRxYwtEbLYhqawmKR/fR1ZfJ418e76PB1snYy4nMynW0sXhCpnr67vglJeIcfHPmNj2ThhNVhSLEGxwPh8nY0x8jHOzasJpt8bL3ElDCcz2azS6IQzbMlYk4IWSuVaAiPxopLRzVu@s5je3Ln4QKRBHLHjsVHCmz6f4BKKA9wgLKCmR3soCpgZgtbKPawRyxuRGCRUvSB3oJKrJBr9sxe2Kui9Ko9Xq8yYqerbh0I8H3rBkjBACqgKqGqIAOKpt/aWH0OU157/wc)

Manual implementation, yay!

Comment: I cut that down a bit (so close to beating the new Python one...) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5Ba8IwGEDv/RWfoYekSafCdlgwY1AvBb1KRxYwtEbLYhqawmKR/fR1ZfJ418e76PB1snYy4nMynW0sXhCpnr67vglJeIcfHPmNj2ThhNVhSLEGxwPh8nY0x8jHOzasJpt8bL3ElDCcz2azS6IQzbMlYk4IWSuVaAiPxopLRzVu@s5je3Ln4QKRBHLHjsVHCmz6f4BKKA9wgLKCmR3soCpgZgtbKPawRyxuRGCRUvSB3oJKrJBr9sxe2Kui9Ko9Xq8yYqerbh0I8H3rBkjBACqgKqGqIAOKpt/aWH0OU157/wc "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: The Python one got cut down too. But if his argument that subtractive notation doesn't need to be supported is upheld, then there are more savings here too.

Comment: In any case, another 3 bytes off with `l=1:4:5:9:map(10*)l`.

Comment: I remembered a remainder trick I once found for converting Roman numerals, which takes care of subtraction automatically. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBa4IhHIDxe5/in3RQX90q2EVyDNol2K7jBRMSnSVTX8nY6iX20eeCDs/hgd/B1K/PGJuX2@aH6CKeEqUffoajq5P6Ar/4LC5iJNMso6mnGb6jbYLAn1MX@JKmwcFtyVyFq13xzLBjgaz4GArafPRv69d3FJmV0mlRiVCXnd@dxXjFntk7U7gjDPNblDAXvjXqOH1ELEuprNaTKBfiSSRT8GJOSWzJhAwSyjHkE8zAA1pDv4G@Bwodan/WR7OvjdtS/gE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 57 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
θ{:u=?F!!}F:u=‽0AøF{1"IVXLCDM”GWH∫2%3*⁽*}aa⁵<⌡±;A}a¹∑ι}}⁰
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwM0I4JTdCJTNBdSUzRCUzRkYlMjElMjElN0RGJTNBdSUzRCV1MjAzRDBBJUY4RiU3QjElMjJJVlhMQ0RNJXUyMDFER1dIJXUyMjJCMiUyNTMqJXUyMDdEKiU3RGFhJXUyMDc1JTNDJXUyMzIxJUIxJTNCQSU3RGElQjkldTIyMTEldTAzQjklN0QlN0QldTIwNzA_,inputs=QyUyMFhJJTIwWFglMjAqJTIwKw__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Node) + [romans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/romans) + [stk-lang](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stk-lang), 74 bytes

```js
s=>(R=require)("stk-lang")(s.replace(/\w+/g,R("romans").deromanize)).stack
```

Returns a list of bigintegers.

### Execution

Run the following:

```
npm install romans
npm install stk-lang
node
```

Then paste the function. Example:

```
C:\Users\conorob\Programming\golf-new\roman
λ npm install romans
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\conorob\Programming\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\conorob\Programming\package.json'
npm WARN Programming No description
npm WARN Programming No repository field.
npm WARN Programming No README data
npm WARN Programming No license field.

+ romans@1.0.0
added 1 package in 0.801s

C:\Users\conorob\Programming\golf-new\roman
λ npm install stk-lang
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\conorob\Programming\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\conorob\Programming\package.json'
npm WARN Programming No description
npm WARN Programming No repository field.
npm WARN Programming No README data
npm WARN Programming No license field.

+ stk-lang@1.0.0
added 1 package in 0.847s

C:\Users\conorob\Programming\golf-new\roman
λ node
> s=>(R=require)("stk-lang")(s.replace(/\w+/g,R("romans").deromanize)).stack
[Function]
> f=_
[Function]
> f("X I + X I - CC II +").map(e => e.toString())
[ '11', '9', '202' ]
> f("C XI XX * +").map(e => e.toString())
[ '320' ]
> f("MMMM M I - +").map(e => e.toString())
[ '4999' ]
```

Comment: How many people use a lambda as prompt?

Comment: @StanStrum I like it, and it's the default for terminals like [cmder](http://cmder.net/)

Comment: Didn't know that. Guess I've never deviated from `$` and `>`. Honestly, I like it though

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 93 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
a←⍬⋄{0::{a,←⍵}roman⍵⋄f←⍎'+-÷×'⌷⍨'+-/*'⍳⍵⋄r←f/¯2↑a⋄a↓⍨←¯2⋄a,←r}¨{1↓¨⍵⊂⍨⍵∊' '}' ',⍞⋄a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pjpHqqek5RWrcyU@apvwqHfNo@6WagMrq@pEHTB/a21Rfm5iHpABlEgDC/Wpa@se3n54uvqjnu2PelcAefpa6o96N0PUFAHVpOkfWm/0qG1iIpAPNHYyUBVQFCQG5IPMLao9tKLaEChzaAVIV1cTSAWQ0dGlrqBeC8Q6j3rngRRzRSh4KmgrgEhdBWdnBU8QT0vB2VNBHwA)

[116 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY6xCsJAEER/ZbvTxONiwEbsYhPQVmwPJDaCYichjUiQ6Ilikc5CGwvBQkWwNH@yPxLn1GKXneExO3oykoOZHo2HZRlxutUYNhdeLWKv2dQ1SFf5sWRzqrB5tdg8qpwdcSbKq7E5x0Wu6pzufWqwucMQYa/fCdpdweYGOnmfsZEXfZM3wpXFs8gFr58WdqVy/iSYKZhIva8@pzsNjTZ7UHCtB237TBEZ25e/5GxuCRzLTJBIMKh1sHBZ9ikkl@yWFAQUWuVQEJL6AA) without the roman built-in

Comment: Woah, never saw modified assignment in a golf before

Comment: @Zacharý it's the only way I know to modify a variable out of its dfns scope, so it _had_ to be used here.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is modified assignment?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing `var fn←arr` - it's equivalent to `var ← var fn arr`. Here it's used in multiple places, `a,←⍵` being one which appends `⍵` to the variable `a`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>280</s> 206 bytes

```python
N=dict(I=1,V=5,X=10,L=50,C=100,D=500,M=1000)
def d(s):
	n=0
	for v in map(N.get,s):n+=v-n%v*2
	return n
def c(w):
	s=[]
	for t in w.split():s+=[str(d(t)if t[0]in N else eval(s.pop(-2)+t+s.pop()))]
	return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1Ba4QwEIXP@ivmUpyYKNld9rKQU3oRWo9LwHpYNLYBG4OZuvTXW@2WXobv8d7HhG/6mPxpXWvVu46wUgdxVWdh1EGKF3WWQm8kxfOGUrzuLFna2wF6jOySJl7JNBmmGRZwHj5vAevy3ZLYSs/VUvinJT@myWzpa/bgf9UO77saVdM@XNrdexnD6AjZJXLVRJqxR2JuAGpku/U12DFasMttxFiGKWBxZJz4gxlj7f@buIbZecK8w0yDqcAYyIGDgervFqA1VHvSZl9cgWdMQLRBZW8@Y@sP)

This time with subtractive notation support. Method `c` is the main entry point; the other is support.

Edit log:

- 74 down thanks to [Ørjan](https://tio.run/##PY1Ba4QwEIXP@ivmUpyYKNld9rKQU3oRWo9LwHpYNLYBG4OZuvTXW@2WXobv8d7HhG/6mPxpXWvVu46wUgdxVWdh1EGKF3WWQm8kxfOGUrzuLFna2wF6jOySJl7JNBmmGRZwHj5vAevy3ZLYSs/VUvinJT@myWzpa/bgf9UO77saVdM@XNrdexnD6AjZJXLVRJqxR2JuAGpku/U12DFasMttxFiGKWBxZJz4gxlj7f@buIbZecK8w0yDqcAYyIGDgervFqA1VHvSZl9cgWdMQLRBZW8@Y@sP)

Comment: You don't need the indentation blocks after `if` and `else`.

Comment: Actually, let me offer you this trick I once found: `n+=v-n%v*2`

Comment: You can also combine the two `str` uses. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1Ba4QwEIXP@ivmUpyYKNld9rKQU3oRWo9LwHpYNLYBG4OZuvTXW@2WXobv8d7HhG/6mPxpXWvVu46wUgdxVWdh1EGKF3WWQm8kxfOGUrzuLFna2wF6jOySJl7JNBmmGRZwHj5vAevy3ZLYSs/VUvinJT@myWzpa/bgf9UO77saVdM@XNrdexnD6AjZJXLVRJqxR2JuAGpku/U12DFasMttxFiGKWBxZJz4gxlj7f@buIbZecK8w0yDqcAYyIGDgervFqA1VHvSZl9cgWdMQLRBZW8@Y@sP "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScipt (ES6), <s>152</s> 151 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to user202729*

```js
p=>p.split` `.map(c=>s.push(eval("+-/*".indexOf(c)+1?(T=s.pop(),s.pop())+c+T:c.replace(/./g,c=>"+"+{I:1,V:5,X:10,L:50,C:100,D:500,M:1e3}[c]))),s=[])&&s
```

### Test cases

```js
f=p=>p.split` `.map(c=>s.push(eval("+-/*".indexOf(c)+1?(T=s.pop(),s.pop())+c+T:c.replace(/./g,c=>"+"+{I:1,V:5,X:10,L:50,C:100,D:500,M:1e3}[c]))),s=[])&&s
console.log(f("C XI XX * +"))
console.log(f("X I + X I - CC II +"))
```

### Explanation (less golfed)

```
V={I:1,V:5,X:10,L:50,C:100,D:500,M:1e3}     // Values of the roman numerals
p=>(
 s=[],                                      // Initialize the stack
 p.split` `.map(c=>                         // For every part in the input:
  "+-/*".indexOf(c)+1?                      //   If the input is an operator:
   s.push(eval((T=s.pop(),s.pop())+c+T))    //     Evaluate the operator on the top of the stack
  :                                         //   Else (if it is a roman numeral):
   s.push(eval(c.replace(/./g,c=>"+"+V[c])))//     Push the sum of the characters' values
 ),s)                                       // return the stack
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `1e3` also work and save some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 82 bytes

```
ị“+-×÷”;”/v®ṫ-¤®ṖṖ¤;©
4Ḷ⁵*p1,5P€
“IVXLCDM”iÐ€ị¢µIN‘Ṡæ.µ®;©
Ḳµ“+-*/”W€i⁸Ñ⁸Ç¤¹?µ€ṛ®Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u5HDXO0dQ9PP7z9UcNcayDWLzu07uHO1bqHloDoaUB0aIn1oZVcJg93bHvUuFWrwFDHNOBR0xouoEbPsAgfZxdfoK7MwxOAYkDjDi06tNXT71HDjIc7Fxxepndo66F1IN0Pd2w6tBVslZY@UHk4UHHmo8YdhyeCiHagXTvtgfJAE3bOBlq7o@v///@eYQphngoRLgrOLgqengpaAA)

[Originally posted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=42020350#42020350).

---

Explanation:

Because Jelly doesn't have a stack, I put the stack in the register.

When the program starts, the register value `®` is `0`, which is treated as `[0]` for the purposes of this program.

```
ị“+-×÷”;”/v®ṫ-¤®ṖṖ¤;©       Link 1: Given an operator index (an
                            integer in range 1..4), apply it.

ị“+-×÷”                     Index to the string "+-×÷"
       ;”/                  Concatenate with the character "/",
                            which is Jelly splat operator.
          v   ¤             Evaluate with parameter...
           ®                  the register's
            ṫ                 tail
             -                from -1. (2 last items)
               ®  ¤;        Concatenate with the register value,
                ṖṖ            pop twice.
                    ©       Store the result to register.

4Ḷ⁵*p1,5P€          Link 2: Niladic, generate [1,5,10,50,...]
4Ḷ                  Lowered range of 4, gives [0,1,2,3].
  ⁵*                Raise to power of 10. Value = 1,10,100,1000.
    p1,5            Calculate Cartesian product with [1,5].
                      Value = [1,1],[1,5],[10,1],[10,5],...
        P€          Calculate product of each item.

Alternatively, ×þ1,5F would also work instead of p1,5P€.

“IVXLCDM”iÐ€ị¢µIN‘Ṡæ.µ®;©   Link 3: Given roman number, push it
                            to the stack (register).
         i                  Find index of ...
          Ð€                  each character ...
“IVXLCDM”                     in "IVXLCDM".
            ị¢              Index to last link. (link 2)
              µ             With that value, (consider LIX ->
                            [50,1,10] for example)
               I             
Ḳµ“+-*/”W€i⁸Ñ⁸Ç¤¹?µ€ṛ®Ḋ

[TODO complete explanation]
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>216</s> 187 bytes

```python
from operator import*
N=dict(I=1,V=5,X=10,L=50,C=100,D=500,M=1000)
def f(w):
	s=[]
	for t in w.split():s+=[str(sum(map(N.get,t)))if t[0]in N else str(eval(s.pop(-2)+t+s.pop()))]
	return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxasMwFEXn@Cve5vdsxSgtWQKa3MXQeiwCN4NppFRgS0J6aejXuwrtcjkXDif@8Ffwz9tmU1ghRJNmDgncGkPiphrVxX0yDuog3tVRaHWQ4lUdpegLSfFSUIq3B0uqLsaCxTudql1W07na2VJicB7uXY6LY6RTbtWUOWG@rbjOEcfualgwETkLPMlzsUcwSzbw0Mz3vGDuYoi4f6KW2z8uesknw7fkIW8xOc/YWKx70ANoDQ20oGH43z30PQzl1SQgm6jqD1/T9gs)

Because it came up in the comments of both the question and this answer and likely led to down-votes: **this submission doesn't support subtractive notation.** Rationale: Subtractive notation was rarely used in the Roman Empire and only popularised later (see [Subtractive Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subtractive_notation&oldid=788980081), paragraph 3, last sentence). The task presumes a Roman Empire that developed programmable integrated circuits, not one that underwent the same cultural changes as 13th century Europe. The description doesn't mention subtractive notation and none of the examples uses it.

Comment: Hm... you're not supporting numbers like `CIV` (104).

Comment: ...can't fault your logic there. :P

Comment: Agh, you were right. I hadn't thought about the possible ambiguity, I wasn't aware subtractive notation wasn't a common feature in the Ancient Roman empire.

Comment: I did actually consider asking about subtractive notation under the OP (and noticed the lack of an example), but got distracted. If you think of definition ambiguities in future challenges, don't hesitate, just ask (answering with a caveat and a link to your comment should do if you want to post). Now a ruling is in you should attempt to fix it up :)